# Redirect loop while extend controller Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops, redirect

I have a problem in login application in codeigniter , the problem is like this:

I create MY_Controller, like this:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }


}
```

Then I extended it on my library that i created, this is my "Petugas_Controller" library:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Petugas_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('petugas_m');

    } // end contructor.


    public function check(){

        if ($this->uri->uri_string() !== 'index' && ! $this->petugas_m->is_logged_in() == TRUE){     
            redirect('admin/petugas/index');
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using that library to be used in my "Petugas" controller, like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Petugas extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('petugas_controller');
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $CI->check();

    }


    public function index(){

        echo "You have to login";
    }

    public function dashboard(){

        echo "Welcome to dashboard";

    }


}
```

In "Petugas_Controller" library, I loaded model that is called "Petugas_m", here is the model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Petugas_m extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function is_logged_in(){

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

That's all what i was trying, and my problem is I want to check if username is logged or not, by doing $this->check() in "Petugas_library" that loads "Petugas_m" model, i could see an dashboard echo if the "check" method in "Petugas_m" is set to TRUE but it's always redirect me a loop if it FALSE.

I was searching for tutorials and still have this crazy problem :( ,
Thank in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Put your `check()` function in `MY_Controller`. Then you have access to it in any controller using `$this->check()`

Comment: tahnks Charlieftl, but it still not working, I can use that check only if I put that out of my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your petugas_controller library is located within the libraries folder, you can access the check method via

```
$this->petugas_controller->check();
```

Also try changing the if statement in your check to something more like this

```
if ($this->uri->uri_string() !== 'index' &&  $this->petugas_m->is_logged_in() !== TRUE){
```

Comment: thanks William, I've already did your suggest, but it's sillt not working, it's only working if I put "$this->petugas_controller->check();" in the functions, but if I put it on the constructor, it's still redirecting loop.

Answer (score 0):

lol, I've just realized my mistake here, I've just tried to make another controller, it's called login, then in my "petugas_controller" library I redirect the user if not login to this "login" controller, it's totally worked ... 
Youy guys are inspiring me so much,Thanks :)